How to get the IP address location from using Python?
My website has to find the user location to determine whether they are in my country or not. I have the user's IP address, but there isn't a way to get the user's IP location. How can I use Python to get the user's IP location? I am not a beginner to Python but I can't find a way to get IP's location.
The code I tried
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def getLocation(ip):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    timeout = 20
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://mycurrentlocation.net/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    country = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="country"]')
    driver.quit()
    return country

print(getLocation(ip))


Apparently you have the IP of whoever is using your website.
However, you are retrieving their location by submitting their IP to another website and scraping the information from the result, after loading the website in Selenium.
There are several issues with this approach:

Selenium has to load an entire web browser, just for this single page
You're loading an entire website, with all its chrome, even though you just need the location for the IP

You would be better off using an appropriate API. There are many solutions out there, and I'm only suggesting one that works - this is not an endorsement, and there may be faster, and more accurate services out there. However, here is a solution that uses geocoder, which allows interaction with several common APIs.
Install it with something like pip install geocoder, then this would work:
import geocoder

ip = '<the IP you have>'

location = geocoder.ip(ip)
print('Location:', location.address)
print('Coordinates:', location.latlng)

Example output (for my IP):
Location: Brisbane, Queensland, AU
Coordinates: [-27.4679, 153.0281]

(don't worry, I'm not actually physically at those coordinates - but I'm in that city)

The code you pasted is scraping a website which is not usually best practice as webpages often change their content or schema, breaking your application.
You can use IPlocation to tell you the IP address's location using requests from Python's standard library and it will return the IP location.
import requests


# define a function to get IP address location
def get_ip_location(ip_address: str = ""):
    """Returns a json with information about an IP address: city, country, lat/long, etc."""
    response = requests.get(f"https://iplocation.co/{ip_address}")
    return response.json()

# random IP addresses
ips = [
    "67.121.66.82",
    "112.141.14.183",
    "184.224.149.37",
    "223.219.170.112",
]

# get the IP location and print it
for ip in ips:
    loc = get_ip_location(ip)
    print(loc)

# or just print the country since you only wanted country
for ip in ips:
    loc = get_ip_location(ip)
    print(loc["country"])

